# What syntax core.logic matche, defne pattern matching constructs use?

Tags: clojure, logic-programming, clojure-core.logic

Some of core.logic constructs (`matcha`, `matche`, `matchu`, `defne`, `fne`) use pattern matching expressions as body and can be used such as:

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [a o]
    (== a [1 2 3 4 5])
    (matche [a]
            ([ [1 2 . [3 4 5] ]]
             (== q "first"))
            ([ [1 2 3 . [4 5] ]]
             (== q "second"))
            ([ [1 . _] ]
             (== q "third")))))
;=> ("first" 
;    "second"
;    "third")
```

(example from [Logic-Starter wiki](https://github.com/frenchy64/Logic-Starter/wiki#matche-sugar-list-destructuring))

But I can't find specification of syntax for pattern matching in core.logic documentation. What is this syntax? Maybe I can find it in some minikanren docs or books?

- What is difference between matched variables prefixed with `?` and without it?
- Is there any other destructing constructs in addition to lists with `.` (similar to `&` in clojure)?
- Will `[_ _]` match only sequences with two elements?
- Is it possible to destruct maps?

Comment: `_` expands to `(lvar)` ([see here](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj#L1506)). I don't think there is anything special about the `?o` vs `o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do my best to answer here. Intel from Ambrose Bonnaire-Sergeant's [notes](https://github.com/frenchy64/Logic-Starter/wiki), which is the only place I could find that had any real documentation on the subject. My suspicion is that a lot of the syntax can be found buried in the research papers upon which `core.logic` is based, but as those are 270-page dissertations I didn't think they'd make a great reference.

**What is difference between matched variables prefixed with ? and without it?**

Variables prefixed with ? are [implicitly declared](https://github.com/frenchy64/Logic-Starter/wiki#matche-sugar-implicit-variables) instead of needing to be declared as an argument to `fresh`. In all other regards they behave the same.

**Is there any other destructing constructs in addition to lists with . (similar to & in clojure)?**

No, there are no other missing pieces of magical syntax for destructuring.

**Will [_ _] match only sequences with two elements?**

Yes.

**Is it possible to destruct maps?**

Not really. There's a good long-form article on the subject you can read [here](http://michaelrbernste.in/2013/05/12/featurec-and-maps.html), but essentially maps and map-like structures have not historically been a subject of focus for the solvers that provide the theoretical underpinnings for `core.logic` and its ilk. If you're interested in logic solving on maps, probably the best tool you have at your disposal is [featurec](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.logic/featurec). To quote the documentation:

> `(featurec x fs)`
>
> Ensure that a map contains at least the key-value
>   pairs in the map `fs`. `fs` must be partially instantiated - that is, it
>   may contain values which are logic variables to support feature
>   extraction.

Comment: The `?` variable syntax was removed in 2011: https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/commit/b1ab2dbde8fa9a6332268c1810f586516baedf15